# Reading SAS Dataset into Oracle

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, sas

I have installed SAS Enterprise Guide 9.3 and SAS JDBC Drivers 9.3 and have some test SAS data sets that I need to load into Oracle. We have licenses for

ODBC SAS/ACCESS ODBC
PCFILE SAS/ACCESS PC File Formats
CONNECT SAS/CONNECT
WKSPSRVLOCAL SAS Workspace Server for Local Access

I am using Windows 7. I am not sure about next steps

1. Can I read SAS Datasets having just installed SAS EG?
2. Which JAR files are required
3. How will the connect string look like and what will be the port, username & password.

Appreciate any help I can get.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in this.  If you can do this, you will need to connect through the local Workspace server.  I've only connected through a server Workspace server to get a JDBC connection.

How I've done it in the past.  Always possible this is not the best method.

Step 1.  Connect to SAS workspace.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/itechjcdg/61499/HTML/default/viewer.htm#connfact_direct.htm

Step 2.  Use the DataService on the Workspace to get a JDBC connection to the current SAS session.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/itechjcdg/61499/HTML/default/viewer.htm#jdbcconn.htm

Alternative:  Connect through ODBC to Oracle in SAS and use SAS to write the tables into your Oracle DB.  See the SAS/ACCESS documentation. http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/access/index.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I cannot use SAS/ACCESS since I dont have the licenses for SAS/ACCESS for Relational Databases.

Just a question - using the local EG, the server is using DOM and I cannot find a listening port to use in the connection URL. What should be the port? After starting the server, I can see couple of new connections in netstat output but the port number is random (it changes with every restart).

Comment: You state you have SAS/ACCESS for ODBC.  That means you can connect to the Oracle database through a ODBC connection.

Comment: I am not sure how would it work. Can I do the following:
Use the SAS/ACCESS for ODBC and be able to load the dataset to Oracle using EG? It would be great if this is possible and do you have any link to documentation that explains this approach

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Look at the documentation above.  It should show you how to set up the libname to use your Oracle ODBC connection.  Oracle tables will show up as datasets in that library.  Simply use PROC APPEND to add observations.